# Is it possible to use Keras to optimize the coefficients of a mathematical function?

Tags: tensorflow, optimization, keras

I'm very new to **Keras a neural network** in general.
 and I was wondering if I had a **list of points** `(x,y)` that came from a quadratic function that looks like this `(ax^2+bx+c)` is it possible

- to feed the points into a neural network and
- get the coefficients `a,b and c` as an output from the network?

  I know that I can simply use polynomial regression to achieve my goal. that is not the point.

Comment: "I know that I can simply use polynomial regression to achieve my goal. that is not the point." what does this sentence mean? What you are asking is exactly polynomial regression.

Comment: I know but I was just curious if a neural network can do it

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking how to do polynomial regression using neural networks, here's the recipe.

Your dataset consists of points `(x, y)`. Design your network to be a fully connected network (dense network) with 1 input layer and 1 output layer. The input layer consists of 2 nodes, the output layer consists of 1 node. Then, give to your network the inputs `x` and `x^2`. The output will be computed as:

```
y = w * X + c
```

where `w` is a matrix of learnable parameters. Specifically, it has shape 1x2 since it contains parameters `a` and `b`. `c` is a bias. The input matrix `X` has shape 2xN, where `N` is the number of points in your dataset and for each point, the first component is `x^2` and the second component is `x`.

As loss function, use the standard Mean Squared Error loss. As for the optimizer, a simple Stochastic Gradient Descent should work just fine. At convergence, `w` and `c` will be good enough to approximate the true quadratic function.

---

I don't know keras, but I think it will not tough figuring out by yourself how to implement this naive network.